# How to get HTTP Status code by mod_status or other ways?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I am exploring mod_status for apache monitoring but I am not getting the way to get HTTP status code by this. I also want to monitor request serve per Hr or Day. That info also missing while enable the mod_status.

Does any body have idea like how to get those info ?
- HTTP Status Code >400
- Historical data or request. (if I fetch the server-status every 15 min, than history of the request between 1-15min

Comment: Please search for a monitoring tool. Mod_status will provide the information used by the monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

mod_status module is **NOT** used for checking http codes. Please read the documentation
[MOD_STATUS](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html).

I can however tell you that if you wish to gather statistics you can do so by either getting tools to query your apache log files, write a script to do that for you or use [awstat](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) for a more comprehensive stats collection for apache. Pretty powerful.

Comment: Please let me know how do I parse apache log file to get statistic. Share me if you have any perl/shell script for that.

Comment: As I mentioned you should look at awstat, go to their website install the app and see if thats the stats your require. I currently don't have scripts for that. But it's easy to create one. You should start somewhere as scripting IS the backbone of a sys admin.